# Metafunction returning element type using decltype

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, decltype

I have the following MWE:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    public:
        using message_type = T;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo<int>> ptr;
    decltype(ptr)::element_type::message_type number = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

and I would like to have a shorthand way to access the `message_type` type of a variable (such as `ptr`) without having to write out the whole `decltype(ptr)::element_type::message_type` part. I.e. have some alias to `decltype(ptr)::element_type::message_type` along the lies of `message_type(ptr)`, which would have the same result.

My first idea was along the lines of

```
template<typename T>
using message_type = decltype(T)::element_type::message_type;
```

which seems logical at first, but it's actually mixing concepts of types and variables, so it does not even compile. My only working solution so far is

```
#define MSG_TYPE(x) decltype(x)::element_type::message_type
```

however I'd like to avoid using macros.

Is this even possible with current C++ metaprogramming? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: maybe `template<typename T>
using message_type = T::element_type::message_type;` using it through `decltype()` (I mean: `message_type<decltype(ptr)> number = 5;`) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
using message_type = typename T::element_type::message_type;

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    public:
        using message_type = T;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Foo<int>> ptr;
    message_type<decltype(ptr)> number = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't think you can do much better as you aren't allowed to use `std::shared_ptr` as a non-type template parameter so you have to do `message_type<decltype(ptr)>`, `message_type<ptr>` is not possible to implement (yet).

Comment: I think this is the correct answer... I'll accept it after some time unless someone has anything more to add.